# Optimal Way to insert from DBLink - Oracle

Tags: oracle, optimization, query-optimization, database-link

I need to insert 10 million records via Dblink into my database.

Do the normal insert statement 
insert into 
select * from   would be the right or optimal way?

What other option could there be to insert data of this volume?

I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: What about expdp/impdp with append? (If both databases are Oracle of course)

Comment: I'd say the fastest way to import 10 mln records is use sqlldr, but right solution is really depends on your environment

Comment: Assuming both databases are tuned to do such a thing (appropriate redo space, etc), I'd say this certainly be the easiest way to do it, and it should be pretty fast and server-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

For 10 million Records we can use EXPDP/IMPDP also be cautious that we cannot copy data for partitioned tables across dblinks ( we need to create temp non partition table load data locally and then copy over database link)

Thanks,
Kalyan

Answer (score 0):

To find optimal way (using DBLINK) you must define your optimization criteria...

Simple first **estimate the required time of the insert**. Test with 10.000 rows and multiply the time with 1.000 - you'll get approximation of the whole statement duration. If the time is acceptable, you're done.

If not, calculate the reached transfer rate MB/sec and compare it with your network througput. You will see if there is improvement possible.

Next option is **direct path insert** - use APPEND hint (on the target side) and select via link from the remote side.

If this imporvement isn't enough (and you have still theoretical improvement), the last resort is **parallel insert**. Unfortunatelly this not possible ti do via PARALLEL hint and you must open N inserts to N temporary tables or N partitions of an temporary table.

You see that getting speed cost some effort, so you must find your own optimum...

I do not go much in detail as for each option its easy to find additional information.